# Creating and Using Scopes In Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, scopes

How do i use scopes in Active Admin, In this example I am trying to display all members who's expiry date is equal to today's date.

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
--- Code removed for brevity


#Scopes
  scope :expired_today, where(:expiry_date == Date.today)
end
```

Within the active admin dashboard i then want to display all those members who have expired

```
columns do

   column do
    panel "Expired Memberships", :class => 'expiredmemberships' do
     table_for Member.expired_today do 
       column("Name")  do |m| 
         "#{m.forename}  #{m.surname}" 
       end
     end
   end
  end 
 end
```

This is not working though, could someone give me a helping hand with an explanation on what needs to be done please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`where` works with scopes the same way it works everywhere else in Rails:

```
where(:expiry_date => Date.today)
```

You give it a hash with a key/value.  Your way, using `==`, basically invokes `where(false)`, as the `==` isn't "passed in", it's resolved instantly (to false as a symbol and date will always be unequal) and the resulting value is passed to `where`.

Comment: you know what i just realised, so silly of me, ill credit the answer to you though, thanks for explaining